# Sequelize many to many relationship does not show the result on GET request

Tags: node.js, rest, express, sequelize.js

I am new in the relational database. I am using node js and express for the backend, REST API and database is Postgresql. I am using Sequelize for connection and models. I have created two models, one is a student and another is a course. My goal is One student can have multiple courses and also want to prevent duplicate student name, phone, email. I successfully connect to the database and able to post, get, update, delete both student and course models. From testing the app I am using Postman. But when I am trying to get request all students or courses. I don't see any relationship between students and course. Here is the visualization [students get request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0L3jh.png) and [courses get request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zEJOC.png).
**This is the [live code](https://codeshare.io/2KpbzX) if anyone wants to help me **

```
const sequelize = require("sequelize");

var con = new sequelize("school", "postgres", "password", {
  host: "localhost",
  dialect: "postgres",

  pool: {
    max: 5,
    min: 0,
    idle: 10000
  }
});

const Student = con.define("student", {
  id: {
    type: sequelize.INTEGER,
    primaryKey: true
  },
  name: {
    type: sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false
  },
  birthday: {
    type: sequelize.DATEONLY,
    allowNull: false
  },
  address: {
    type: sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false
  },
  zipcode: {
    type: sequelize.INTEGER,
    allowNull: false
  },
  city: {
    type: sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false
  },
  phone: {
    type: sequelize.BIGINT,
    allowNull: false
  },

  email: {
    type: sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
    validate: {
      isEmail: true
    }
  }
});

const Course = con.define("course", {
  id: {
    type: sequelize.INTEGER,
    primaryKey: true
  },
  name: { type: sequelize.STRING },
  startdate: { type: sequelize.DATEONLY },
  enddate: { type: sequelize.DATEONLY },
  studentId: { type: sequelize.INTEGER, foreignKey: true }
});

const StudentCourse = con.define("studentCourses", {
  id: {
    type: sequelize.INTEGER,
    primaryKey: true
  },
  courseId: { type: sequelize.INTEGER, foreignKey: true },
  studentId: { type: sequelize.INTEGER, foreignKey: true }
});

Student.belongsToMany(Course, { through: StudentCourse, as: "courses" });
Course.belongsToMany(Student, { through: StudentCourse, as: "students" });

//con.sync({ force: true });

module.exports = { Student, Course, StudentCourse };
```

**This is my REST API by using Node and Express server. How I can display the relational to the browser.**

```
      require("dotenv").config();
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const morgan = require("morgan");
const helmet = require("helmet");
const cors = require("cors");

const { Student, Course, StudentCourse } = require("./db");
//app middlewear

app.use(morgan("common"));
app.use(helmet());
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json()); //body Parser

//student

app.get("/students", async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    await Student.findAll({
      include: {
        model: Course,
        through: StudentCourse,
        as: "courses"
      }
    }).then(docs => {
      const response = {
        count: docs.length,
        students: docs
      };
      res.json(response);
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});

app.get("/students/:id", async (req, res, next) => {
  const id = req.params.id;
  try {
    Student.findByPk(id).then(data => {
      console.log(data);
      res.json(data);
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});

app.put("/students/:id", async (req, res) => {
  const id = req.params.id;
  const update = req.body;
  try {
    await Student.update(update, { where: { id } }).then(data => {
      res.json(data);
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});

app.delete("/students/:id", async (req, res, next) => {
  const id = req.params.id;

  try {
    Student.destroy({ where: { id } }).then(data => {
      res.json(data);
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});

app.post("/students", async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const logs = new Student(req.body);
    const entry = await logs.save();
    res.json(entry);
  } catch (error) {
    if (error.name === "ValidationError") {
      res.status(422);
    }
    next(error);
  }
});

//course

app.get("/courses", async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    await Course.findAll({
      include: {
        model: Student,
        through: StudentCourse,
        as: "students"
      }
    }).then(docs => {
      const response = {
        count: docs.length,
        courses: docs
      };
      res.json(response);
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});

app.get("/courses/:id", async (req, res, next) => {
  const id = req.params.id;
  try {
    Course.findByPk(id).then(data => {
      console.log(data);
      res.json(data);
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});

app.put("/courses/:id", async (req, res, next) => {
  const id = req.params.id;
  const update = req.body;
  try {
    await Course.update(update, { where: { id } }).then(data => {
      res.json(data);
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});

app.delete("/courses/:id", async (req, res, next) => {
  const id = req.params.id;

  try {
    Course.destroy({ where: { id } }).then(data => {
      res.json(data);
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});

app.post("/courses", async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const logs = new Course(req.body);
    const entry = await logs.save();
    res.json(entry);
  } catch (error) {
    if (error.name === "ValidationError") {
      res.status(422);
    }
    next(error);
  }
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(port, () => console.log(` App is listening at port ${port}!`));
```

Comment: You can refer to the following blog - https://medium.com/@tonyangelo9707/many-to-many-associations-using-sequelize-941f0b6ac102

Answer (score 0):

For `many-to-many` relationship you have to define a mapping table.

```
const StudentCourse = con.define("studentCourses", {
  id: {
    type: sequelize.INTEGER,
    primaryKey: true
  },
  courseId: { type: sequelize.INTEGER, foreignKey: true },
  studentId: { type: sequelize.INTEGER, foreignKey: true }
});
```

Now, define your associations as below.

```
Student.belongsToMany(Course, { through: StudentCourse, as: 'courses'});
Course.belongsToMany(Student, { through: StudentCourse, as: 'students' });
```

Here is how would you query for `students` with their courses.

```
const studentWithCourses = await Student.findAll({
     include: {
            model: Course,
            through: StudentCourse,
            as: 'courses'
       }    
 })
```

For more information on `many-to-many` association, have a look [here](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/assocs.html#many-to-many-relationships)

Comment: Thank you. I am able to post students but when I am trying get request it throws me this error:  `EagerLoadingError [SequelizeEagerLoadingError]: course is associated to student using an alias. You must use the 'as' keyword to specify the alias within your include statement.`

Comment: Okay I will update the answer so that you can use it.